# Ruby on Rails lambda with left join and condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

Room has_many bookings

Booking belongs_to room

I have this code and it works fine:

```
available_rooms = Room.select {|room| room.bookings.where("day = ?", date).count < 3 || room.bookings.empty?}
```

but I wonder if it is possible to rewrite it like a lambda with left join

```
scope :available, lambda {|date| joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN bookings on bookings.room_id = rooms.id').......
```

I tried this but got back only Rooms WITH at least one Booking, so totally empty rooms WITHOUT Bookings at all were excluded:

```
  def self.available(date)
    # You can use `Arel.star` instead of `:id` on postgres.
    b = Booking.arel_table[:id]
    group(:id)
      .left_joins(:bookings)
      .where(bookings: { day: date })
      .having(b.count.lt(3)) # COUNT(bookings.id) < 3
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! But in this case, I will receive only rooms that have bookings on this Date.
What I need - all rooms that have no bookings on this Date at all + rooms that have bookings on this Date but the total amount of that bookings is < 3 (some N number)

Comment: You could maybe add a having and group clause to your query? `.having("COUNT(date) < 3").group(:id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
To satisfy the requirement you are actually going to need a complex join please try the following instead

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  def self.available(date)
    b = Booking.arel_table
    join_statement = Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(b,
      Arel::Nodes::On.new(
        arel_table[:id].eq(b[:room_id])
          .and(b[:day].eq(Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(date)))
    ))
    group(:id)
      .joins(join_statement)
      .having(b[:id].count.lt(3))
  end
end
```

Here we are LEFT JOINing `bookings` based on the relation to room and the date requested. Now if a room is not booked for that date or it has less than 3 bookings for that date it should show up as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the help! @engineersmnky It almost works but in this case, I have:

- all empty Rooms (without Bookings at all)

- all Rooms with Booking on SOME_DATE with total amount < 3 (or som N)

BUT I don't have

- Rooms that have Bookings but on some other not related days.

Comment: @Irina I see. Updated accordingly with a 2 condition join.

Comment: Thank you again! I'm getting this error, can't really find the problem...

"SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: main.rooms.id"

Comment: @Irina I have no idea how that could be considered ambiguous it seems fully qualified to me. Also I would highly recommend using a production ready database e.g. postgreSQL, mySQL, mariaDB, MSSQL, etc. SQLite has a lot of quirks, most of which I am not familiar enough with to really be able to assist adequately.